# Update specific Pandas DataFrame column with values from another Dataframe column (equivalent to SQL UPDATE with JOIN)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframes:

First:

| Timestamp | Label | Value | Another col 1 | another col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00 | A | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:00 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:15 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:30 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:45 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00 | C | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00 | D | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:15 | D | 0 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Second:

| Timestamp | Label | Value | Unrelated column A | Unrelated column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00 | A | 20 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00 | C | 20 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Take all rows from the `Second` dataframe
2. Find the matching row (by `Timestamp` and `Label`)  in the `First` dataframe (while also ignoring rows for which I can not find the match)
3. Update the `First.Value` column with the values from `Second.Value` column

The final result would be updated `First` dataframe:

| Timestamp | Label | Value | Another col 1 | another col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00 | A | 20 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:00 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:15 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:30 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 00:45 | B | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00 | C | 20 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00 | D | 0 | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:15 | D | 0 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In SQL world I could do something like update with join. I have no idea how to do it in Pandas.
I have looked at DataFrame.update and DataFrame.merge but they all seem to be oriented towards completely merging the two dataframes whereas I just want to copy certain values. It seems it should probably be possible with some sort of multi-index but it is way beyond my knowledge.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I have been asked if this is a duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101). I do not see how it is, I need to update the first DataSet inplace and this does not seem to be possible with `merge`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: use merge with how='left'

Comment: What dtype is the `'Timestamp'` Series? ... `DataFrame.dtypes`

Comment: @wwi datetime64

Comment: Is every `Second[['Timestamp','Label']]` row/combo **in** First?

Comment: @wwii No, there can be values missing from both (the SQL equivalent would be an update with inner join).

Comment: Did you see this Q&A?: [Inner join and update a column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273391/inner-join-and-update-a-column-in-pandas) .

Comment: @wii Would that solution work if I do not have the same rows in both data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's merge these two tables according to **'Timestamp','Label'**. The **df2['Value']** values ​​in the rows that match the first df will not be **nan**, otherwise they will all be **nan**.

After use np.where: if the **df2['Value']** value in df2 is not nan then take that value, if nan then keep the **df1['Value']** value in df1.

```
final=df.merge(df2,on=['Timestamp','Label'],how='left')
final['Value_x']=np.where(final['Value_y'].notnull(),final['Value_y'],final['Value_x'])
final=final.rename(columns={'Value_x':'Value'})
final=final[df.columns]
print(final)
'''
    Timestamp           Label   Value   Another col 1   another col 2
0   2022-01-01 00:00:00 A       20      ...             ...
1   2022-01-01 00:00:00 B       0       ...             ...
2   2022-01-01 00:15:00 B       0       ...             ...
3   2022-01-01 00:30:00 B       0       ...             ...
4   2022-01-01 00:45:00 B       0       ...             ...
5   2022-01-01 01:00:00 C       20      ...             ...
6   2022-01-01 01:00:00 D       0       ...             ...
7   2022-01-01 01:15:00 D       0       ...             ...

'''
```